# Lock computer USB connection

Tags: usb, password

I'm looking for a way to lock computer USB connection with anther password then the regular lock screen password... (or ether disable the usb connection completely without broke the usb port)

There is an app on the play store that called:
Smart AppLock (App Protector)‏ https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free

It has the so-called option "USB Connection Lock", but it isn't working...

**Some one told me** that i need an app or a way that detects whether `com.android.settings/.Settings$UsbDetailsActivity`

activity is in the foreground or not. If in foreground, than create an overlay or a new activity on top of it which would act as a password lock

but how can i do that?

Comment: Why is lock screen password not adequate? Dual lock would achieve nothing. If a person besides you knows lock screen password than they defacto have internal storage data access and app installation privileges.

Comment: No, it for a person that doesn't know the lock screen password, and he can't do a simple factory rest... because i have a TWRP recovery mode with password also.  and he is trying to hack my phone with Usb Connection... so i'm searching for a way to block and Usb connection, even myself to block him. and i want just the battery to work with the usb cable, but never a file transfer or something like that... I don't use the Usb port for anything but charging (sorry for my lame english...)

Comment: You can set the default USB mode to charging only. Check the Developer Options there it should be configurable.